# скопировал начальный код Discord.py и выбивает ошибку: AttributeError: 'Intents' object has no attribute 'message_content'

Tags: python, discord

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='>', intents=intents)

@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send('pong')

bot.run('TOKEN')
```

**Выводит ошибку:**
File "Расположение файла", line 5, in 
intents.message_content = True
AttributeError: 'Intents' object has no attribute 'message_content'

Comment: а что вы хотите добиться? в чём вопрос?

Comment: как исправить ошибку?

Comment: Возможно Вы скачали устаревшую версию модуля. Если используете pycharm, то в поисках пакетов попробуйте найти discord2, а старый удалить. 
Также рекомендую проверить на https://discord.com/developers в разделе Bot найти MESSAGE CONTENT INTENT и поставить галочку.

Как Вам уже написали, проверить версию: print(discord.__version__) после импорта. Актуальная, насколько мне известно 2.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Какая версия библиотеки? Проверить можно так:

```
import discord
print(discord.__version__)
```

Попробуй обновить:

```
pip install --upgrade discord.py
```

Comment: я пробую обновить/ переустановить но все равно качается верстия1.7.3

Comment: pip install discord.py==2.0.1